# Select based on the next business day in a calendar table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, calendar, where-clause

I have a calendar table (Calendar_Date, Is_Business_Day) already filled in.

I have already managed to do a `SELECT` on this basis :

- If today is **before** the 3rd day of the current month, select all the days before this day until the last day of the penultimate month

**For example :** Today is 2018-05-02, this is my output :

```
Calendar_Date |  Is_Business_Day
  2000-01-01  |    0
  ...         |
  2018-03-29  |    1
  2018-03-30  |    1
  2018-03-31  |    0
```

- If today is **after** the 3rd day of the current month, select all the days before this day until the last day of the last month.

**For example :** Tomorrow, 2018-05-03 this will be my output :

```
Calendar_Date | Is_Business_Day
  2000-01-01  |   0
  ...         |  
  2018-04-28  |   0
  2018-04-29  |   0
  2018-04-30  |   1
```

This is my query :

```
SELECT        Calendar_Date, Is_Business_Day
FROM            Calendar_Table
WHERE        (Calendar_Date <= (CASE WHEN DATEPART(day, GETDATE()) >= 3 THEN EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, - 1, GETDATE())) ELSE EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, - 2, GETDATE())) END))
```

This is working perfectly, but what i would like it to do now is to switch after the **first business day** after the 3rd day of the month, instead of switching after the 3rd day of the month.

How can I use the information about business days in my calendar table to do this?

Comment: Doesn't adding `AND Is_Business_Day = 1` to the `WHERE` clause do it?   Your question is unclear because you ask about "switching" without explaining anywhere else in your question you mean by "switching".

Comment: When i add `AND Is_Business_Day = 1` , i get only business days in my selection, but i would also like to have non business days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following query should work.

```
   ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT        Calendar_Date, Is_Business_Day
        FROM          Calendar_Table
        WHERE        (Calendar_Date <= (CASE WHEN DATEPART(day, GETDATE()) >= 3 
                                          THEN EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, - 1, GETDATE())) 
                                  ELSE EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, - 2, GETDATE())) END))
    )
    SELECT * FROM CTE
    WHERE Calendar_Date >= (SELECT MIN(Calendar_Date) FROM CTE WHERE Is_Business_Day=1)
```